# Prevent Windows from removing Ubuntu 18.04 installed on external HDD from boot sequence (UEFI)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in UEFI mode on my external HDD to run on my Dell XPS 15 9570 which has Windows 10 natively installed. I didn't want to dual boot from my internal SSD since I didn't want to change to AHCI and make any drastic changes to the device in general. The HDD is 1TB but I gave Ubuntu about 256GB and formatted the rest to NTFS so I could also use it as external storage for random files on both operating systems.

The install went perfectly. UEFI gave me no real issues. I left Secure Boot on and didn't add the option to boot from Legacy ROMs. I just needed to add Ubuntu to the boot sequence in the UEFI settings/BIOS and set it to load Ubuntu first so when the HDD is connected it loads to Ubuntu and when it isn't it loads to Windows 10 for a plug-and-play effect.

This works very well. However, there is one issue. When I read the HDD in Windows which loads the Ubuntu EFI partition and the NTFS partition separately, it seems to delete Ubuntu from the boot sequence. To add it back I need to re-add Ubuntu from the UEFI settings. I'm not sure what is causing this. I suspect it has something to do with Windows seeing the Ubuntu EFI partition.

Now this isn't a major issue. I could re-add Ubuntu to the boot sequence every time I decide to access the NTFS partition on Windows. But I would prefer not to fiddle around with the BIOS too much.

Has anyone experienced this? Any solutions?

Comment: 1. You can test if there is a problem with a persistent live drive made with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb); 2. If it works, you can use the [method by C.S.Cameron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083330/how-to-make-an-usb-ubuntu-installation-more-compatible-with-different-computers/1083577#1083577) to create an installed system in your external drive.

Comment: Windows syncs BCD & UEFI. That can be part of issue. Also external drives normally boot from ESP on external, if you have default install, you probably are booting from ESP on internal drive. Best to have an ESP - efi system partition (FAT32 with boot flag) on external drive and have /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi in that. You can copy /EFI/Boot & /EFI/ubuntu (you need both with full install) to ESP on external drive.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I do have the EFI folder on the external so I think that wasn't the issue. What seems to solve it is simply ejecting the drive in Windows before restarting to enter Ubuntu so this hasn't been a problem now :)