# How to boot Ubuntu MATE desktop-arm64+raspi3-ext4 from multiboot USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

Have Raspberry Pi3+ that normally runs LibreELEC Kodi.

Would like to be able to occasionally boot Ubuntu MATE on the RPi from my multiboot grub2 USB.

Is this possible?

The Multiboot USB was made similar to: [How to make an USB Ubuntu installation more compatible with different computers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083330/how-to-make-an-usb-ubuntu-installation-more-compatible-with-different-computers/1083812#1083812)