# boot ubuntu 18.04 from external hard drive on a computer with windows 10

Tags: boot, windows, external-hdd

can someone tell me or point me to a guide on how to boot Ubuntu on an external hard drive? i need to move on different machines but on my personal PC my windows don't let me see the hard drive with Ubuntu installation on the boot devices list, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is secure boot enabled? In that case please turn it off and try again. That should let the computer see the external drive at boot time and boot from it. Also, is Ubuntu installed in the same boot mode as Windows (usually UEFI)?

Comment: from what i found that seem to be part of the problem, i had to to turn off the secure boot and yes the UEFI its giving me problems to because apart of my personal pc the other machines do not suport it

Comment: I suggest that you start from an iso file with either 18.04.1 LTS or the newest point release, now 18.04.3 LTS, (not from the original 18.04 LTS).

Comment: On second thought: If some of your computers are old and have 32-bit CPUs, you will not be able to run Ubuntu 18.04.x, because it needs 64-bit architecture. In that case it is possible to make a lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 32-bit system persistent live using `mkusb` with `usb-pack-efi` that can boot both in UEFI and BIOS mode.

Answer (score 0):

You want a portable Ubuntu system, that can boot both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode.

### The easiest solution is to create a persistent live drive

- very portable between computers (unless a computer needs a proprietary driver (for wifi or graphics)
- easy to create with the tool **mkusb**:

  - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb
  - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent
- limits:

  - You can install and update/upgrade most program packages
  - You can *not* make new kernels and kernel drivers (for wifi or graphics) work

### It is possible but more difficult to create a portable installed system

- portable between computers; you may or may not have problems if you install a proprietary driver (for wifi or graphics)
- method to create a portable installed system, bootable both in UEFI and BIOS:

  - [How to make an USB Ubuntu installation more compatible with different computers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083330/how-to-make-an-usb-ubuntu-installation-more-compatible-with-different-computers/1083577#1083577)
  - more details at

    - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS; method up to date, linked image files getting old
    - [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312); more necessary to boot in both UEFI and BIOS mode
- limits:

  - You can install and update/upgrade all program packages including new kernels and kernel drivers (for wifi or graphics)
  - There may be portability problems
  - When booted , major updates of Windows may damage the boot structure of the portable USB drive with an installed system, so it is a good idea to disconnect the drive, when you intend to boot into Windows.