# Burn iso to an external hdd partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, external-hdd, format

I am trying to have multiple USB installers for different  OSs, like Debian, Ubuntu, windows, etc.
I have an external 2T HDD (Seagate Expansion+) with a single partition in it.
What I want to do is to make a few little partitions in it, and burn the different images to those partitions, without affecting the 50 GB of data I have in the main partition, which I can't move anywhere.
I just want something like this:

```
Drive        Size      Bootable

/dev/sdb1    1988 GB  
/dev/sdb2    4 GB       *  
/dev/sdb3    4 GB       * 
/dev/sdb4    4 GB       *
```

With the 4 GB partitions being bootable OS installers, and without formatting the big partition, because there's stuff there I can't move out that I'd like to keep

My operative systems:
Grub dual-boot:

1. ParrotSec OS 4.9 amd64
2. Windows 7 Home Premium

I have tried:

**Multibootusb ->** has bugs and doesn't start

**dd command ->** doesn't support multiboot

**Unetbootin ->** doesn't support multiboot

**YUMI ->** it just gives me access to the live part of the ISO, losing the installer, which is part of my plan

Edit: Nevermind, YUMI did the trick, I just accidentally downloaded a live version only of ubuntu instead of the installer

Edit 2: For future reference I'd like to mention that I currently use [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html), which allows you to just install the tool on the drive, and then just throw ISO files in it. It will show a GRUB-like menu and allow you to choose why ISO file to boot

Comment: Many folks use a VM like [Qemu/KVM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation) for that. Then you don't need separate partitions at all. Just a directory full of .iso files.

Comment: What is your question? Where does Ubuntu come in?

Comment: There are a few ways to burn multiple ISOs to a USB stick, can google it.  Gparted can shrink  your data partition and then make as many small partitions as you like if the drive is GPT.  Can usually only have 4 primary partitions if it is MBR.  Probably should format the small partitions as Fat32.

Comment: answering to mikewhatever:My computer is running windows 7 and parrot sec os (debian based) and what i want is to have my hdd as a multiple os installer I can carry around, because sometimes I get to the point of having to reinstall on of my os. I also have an ubuntu server that has LVM cipher and I want to take it away.

Comment: answering to user535733: I'd like to be able to carry around the installers, like if I had multiple usb sticks with a single iso in each one.

Comment: answering to crip659: i have been googling ways to do that for hours, and i havent found any way of doing that. I have tried etcher (formats everything) i'd try YUMI but i cant find the place to download it, (ik it in pendrivelinux, but it doesnt say download anywhere) multibootusb is broken bc of a bug in its script, and another 2 apps i cant install bc their repos are not available for parrot os.

Comment: MultiBootUSB, (Ubuntu), worked for me today. You can download YUMI here: https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ or you could try a hand made multiboot using the link in my answer.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines You can use grub 2.04 but need `rmmod tpm` in boot stanza. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1851311

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: @Ciro García: UNetbootin will make a Multi Boot USB. You need to create the multiple partitions first and then install to them. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/962536/partitioning-a-usb-and-making-separate-bootable-drives/963731#963731. YUMI is much easier.

Comment: @CiroGarcía, Yes, today many people prefer Ventoy for the task of multibooting live systems and/or installers. -- But I prefer to get (download) current iso files and clone them to an SSD connected via USB. (The content of a multiboot USB drive will soon get old ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YUMI works just fine. I can install anything i want in a single partition and choose whatever I want at start-up.

Comment: I am glad to see that YUMI-UEFI 0.0.2.0 has become YUMI-BIOS/UEFI.0.0.2.2. It worked for me with Ubuntu 20.04 both BIOS mode and UEFI mode. However I had to change the label of casper-rw to writable in order to make persistence work. I also tried it with Clonezilla, GParted, and UBCD. They all worked. I am disappointed with the latest MultiBootUSB. Thank you for posting your solution (+10).

Answer (score 2):

### MultiBoot using External USB HDD

You can use **MultiBootUSB**, http://multibootusb.org/, to install multiple OS to a specific partition on an HDD or each OS to it's own partition. Multiple persistence is also possible.

[image]

MultiBootUSB 9.2 is working with Ubuntu up to 18.04. It will boot 'buntu 20.04 ISO's placed in the /multibootusb/iso/ folder. Persistence and UEFI boot is working with Linux versions but not with the Windows version of MBUSB.

It is easy to just install GRUB to a hard drive and use that to boot ISO files. The following was written for USB but also works on HDD: [How do I create a Multiboot USB that is compatible with both BIOS and UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222380/how-do-i-create-a-multiboot-usb-that-is-compatible-with-both-bios-and-uefi/1222423#1222423)

Comment: I have tried multiboot and i get a few errors trying to start the program

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows MBUSB, Linux is best. What version? 9.2 can boot many OS by dropping the ISO's into the /multibootusb/iso/ folder. Do you need persistence for any of the OS or are they all installers only? Personally I would just install grub to the USB to boot ISO's kept on a NTFS partition, (so they are accessible to Windows and Linux). This can be done by adding a bios_grub partition and a boot,esp partition. The ISO's can be kept in a folder on the existing NTFS partition if there is one. You are only allowed 4 partitions if you are using a msdos partition table.

Comment: The app worked on first try, but after that, it didn't work anymore. Console said `NameError: name 'config' is not defined`