# I have a sd card with Ubuntu installed on it. Can I run Ubuntu from this SD card on another PC on which grub is not installed?

Tags: grub2, 20.04, sd-card

I have a SD card with Ubuntu 20.04 installed on it. Can I run Ubuntu from this Sd card on another PC on which grub is not installed?
Can I just plug the SD card into some Windows PC and then just boot in Ubuntu?

Comment: It depends how you have installed it. If it is installed so that there is a grub bootloader on the SD card, and your other computer can boot from the SD card, yes. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312), that describes how to create such a portable installed system.

Comment: @sudodus Unfortunately, I have the grub bootloader installed on my main drive, but I would like to move it on the SD card. Is this possible inside of ubuntu without breaking/needing to reinstall the entire os?

Comment: It is possible, but maybe easier to re-install. Do you want to boot from the SD card in UEFI mode or BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode), or both (in different computers)?

Comment: @sudodus I think both would be the best way to go.

Comment: If you want a system that boots both in  UEFI mode and BIOS mode, it will be difficult to fix it in an existing system. I think it will be much easier to create a new [persistent live](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) system or rather easy to create an [installed system, that can boot in both boot modes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083330/how-to-make-an-usb-ubuntu-installation-more-compatible-with-different-computers/1083577#1083577).

Comment: Okay, but how can I remove the grub menu from my main drive?

Comment: This is actually a different question, and you might get better help, if you create a new AskUbuntu question for it. That way more people would see it and get interested in helping you. -- What have you got in the internal drive? Is there only Windows or a dual boot system with Windows and Ubuntu in the internal drive?